# Create 3 lines in dc.seriesChart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

How create 3 lines(group1, group2, group3) in dc.seriesChart, in this dashboard - 
https://jsfiddle.net/gubzh/j15szqhk/24/

```
var ndx = crossfilter(records);
var all = ndx.groupAll();
//console.log(all);

var priorityDim         = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.priority; });
var dateDim             = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.timestamp; });
var datePriorityDim     = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return [+d.priority, +d.timestamp];});

var priorityGroup       = priorityDim.group();
var numRecordsByDate    = dateDim.group();
var datePriorityGroup   = datePriorityDim.group().reduceCount();

var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].timestamp;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].timestamp;
priorityTimeChart
    .width(400)
    .height(200)
    .chart(function(c) { return new dc.lineChart(c); })
    .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Events")
    .xAxisLabel("Date")
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(datePriorityGroup)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return "priority: " + d.key[0];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[1];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value;})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));
priorityTimeChart.yAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.format(',d')(d);});
priorityTimeChart.margins().left += 10;
```

For example - 
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/range-series.html

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly got it, but it looks like you've sprinkled `+` everywhere, in an effort to get things to work.

In JavaScript, `+` before an expression is a simple way to convert it to a number.

You usually only need to do this when pulling data from a CSV file, where all the values will be strings.

However, many of the things you were converting were not numbers. In particular you had

```
var datePriorityDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return [+d.priority, +d.timestamp];});
```

which should be

```
var datePriorityDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return [d.priority, d.timestamp];});
```

`d.priority` is a string, and `d.timestamp` is a date. I logged the contents of your group with

```
console.log(datePriorityGroup.all())
```

and noticed that your keys were coming out as

```
[NaN, 1581314400000]
```

Converting the date to a number seems to be harmless, but changing the priority to `NaN` will cause all the priority groups to be binned together. There were only four results where there should be 12.

With the fix:

[image: working series chart screenshot]

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3cxwLkob/9/).

Comment: Thank you, Gordon for your help. That's what I need.